# Check if array exists in array using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

How do I verify if a child array exists in its parent? I have tried [_.includes](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#includes), [_.find](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#find) and [_.findIndex](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#findIndex) without any luck.

```
let arr = [[1],[2],[3]];
let el = [1];

_.includes(arr, el)   // false
_.find(arr, el)       // undefined
_.findIndex(arr, el)  // -1
```

To clarify, the `el` is an *array* that contains *n* amount of integers, whilst `arr` is an *array* that contains *n* amount of arrays.

Edit: added JSBIN: https://jsbin.com/tequcoloro/edit?js,console

Comment: `[1]` is not equal to another `[1]` because they're really different objects with the same content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to walk over the array and compare it's elements.

You can use the `_.isEqual` function to do so:

```js
let arr = [[1],[2],[3]];
let el = [1];

console.log(arr.filter((e) => _.isEqual(e, el)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Lodash is your weapon of choice here you can do:

```
_.findIndex(arr, function (v) { return _.isEqual(v, el); }); // 0
```

Answer (score 2):

If your arrays are ordered you don't have to walk each of them:

```js
let arr = [[1],[2],[3]];
let el = [1];

console.log(
  arr.some(arr => arr.toString() === el.toString())
)
```